# how to update dabase from server and how i know server change database

Tags: android

below is my source code my question is how to update database from server first time application insert values formserver in database now after some time when server update database how will application know server change database now need to update database?

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
static ArrayList<String> Category_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();


     private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private boolean isUpdate;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mHelper=new DbHelper(this);
                dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();


      isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

      // check for Internet status
      if (isInternetPresent) {
          // Internet Connection is Present
          // make HTTP requests
          new TheTask().execute();

      } else {
          // Internet connection is not present
          // Ask user to connect to Internet
          displayData();

      }



         void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();

}

public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

SelectMenuAPI = "http://www.xyz/_webservices/mobile_api.php?response=getmaincategories";

        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

        try {

            Log.i("url", "" + URL2);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL2);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    //         IOConnect = 1;

        }
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);




        try {

            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(result);

            status = json2.getString("Status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);





                    String id = object.getString("category_id");
                    String name =object.getString("name");
                    String  image_path = object.getString("image_path");






                    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MYID,id);

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,name);
                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,image_path );

                    System.out.println("");
                    if(isUpdate)
                    {    
                        //update database with new data 
                dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //insert data into database
                        dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                    }
                    //close database
                    dataBase.close();


                }




                              else {





            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayData();
        }


             }


                      private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

     Category_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MYID)));

      Category_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));

    Category_image.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    gridview.setAdapter(cla);

    mCursor.close();
}






           public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";

public static final String KEY_MYID="myid";


public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY 
 KEY,"+KEY_MYID+" TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" BLOB)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is different approaches to solve this but either you have can refresh your application in some intervals. You can call the web service every X minutes and ask if there is any changes or you can use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html%E2%80%8E) to receive notifications from server and then refresh your data
Hope it helps:)

Comment: suppose i recieve notificaitonwith spesific command like"1" now how my application call update? see my database class which i copy form net this code written  "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " so it will automatcally call and delete previous and insert new data on database??